# Composition Relations (Discrete Mathematics)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $f : A \to A$ and $g : A \to A$ be bijections. Show that $g \circ f$ is a bijection and find its inverse in terms of $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$?

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: why "discrete mathematics"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $(g\circ f)\circ (f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})=g\circ (f\circ f^{-1})\circ g^{-1}=g\circ id_{A}\circ g^{-1}=g\circ g^{-1}=id_{A}$.

Also $(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})\circ (g\circ f)=f^{-1}\circ (g^{-1}\circ g)\circ f=f^{-1}\circ id_{A}\circ f=f^{-1}\circ f=id_{A}$ .

So $(g\circ f)$ is bijective and its inverse is $f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi =g\circ f$.

Let $a,b\in A : \phi(a)=\phi(b)$. Let $f(a)=a'$ and $f(b)=b'$, then $\phi(a)=g(a')$ and $\phi(b)=g(b')$. Since $g$ is injective, $g(a')=g(b')\Rightarrow a'=b'$. Then $f(a)=f(b)$. Since $f$ is also injective, $f(a)=f(b)\Rightarrow a=b$. Hence if $\phi(a)=\phi(b)$ then $a=b$ and thus $\phi$ is injective.

Let $j\in A$. Since $g$ is surjective, $\exists k\in A : g(k)=j$. Since also $f$ is surjective, $\exists l\in A:f(l)=k$. Combining those two we get: $\forall j\in A, \exists l\in A:\phi(l)=g(f(l))=g(k)=j$ and thus surjective.

Now we have $\phi$ is bijective.

The inverse $\phi^{-1}$ is simply $f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$. (Let $g(f(a))=g(a')=a''$, $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(a''))=f^{-1}(a')=a$.